# How to send redirect to JSP page in Servlet

Tags: jsp, redirect, servlets

When I'm done processing in a servlet, and the result is valid, then I need to redirect the response to another JSP page, say `welcome.jsp` in web content folder. How can I do it?

For example:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

         // Some processing code here ...

         // How do I redirect to another JSP here when I'm ready?

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Look at the [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String location)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-) method.

Use it as:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/welcome.jsp")
```

Alternatively, look at [`HttpServletResponse#setHeader(String name, String value)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

The redirection is set by adding the location header:

```
response.setHeader("Location", request.getContextPath() + "/welcome.jsp");
```

Comment: Please do not post examples with invalid syntax.  The sendRedirect() method is not a static method.  Same for setHeader().

Comment: @DSoa just change HttpServletResponse with the response varible defined in your doPost method. No big deal

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below code and let me know

```
try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(c, "root", "MyNewPass");
            System.out.println("connection done");


            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
            System.out.println(q);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("done2");
            while (rs.next()) {
               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
               System.out.println(rs.getString(2));

            }

         response.sendRedirect("myfolder/welcome.jsp"); // wherever you wanna redirect this page.

        }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }
```

**`myfolder/welcome.jsp`** is the relative path of your `jsp` page. So, change it as per your `jsp` page path.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String u = request.getParameter("username");
    String p = request.getParameter("password");

    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName where USERNAME = '" + u + "' and PASSWORD = '"
                + p + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {

            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/invalidLogin.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You could enhance your answer adding some comments to your code or explaining what you are doing instead of just posting the code.

Comment: please don't spread sql injection prone code, even as examples

Comment: @TrevorHarrison you're right. examples are the #1 reason why common security vulnerabilities are still found.