# getXMLHttpRequest : creating new request in javascript

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am to send 200 OK http response with 3 additional things.

1) sending 1.js

2) sending 2.js

3) create new post triggering some url

My code is :

```
out.println("<html><head>");
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/o6/s.js?cacheKey=1313487436055\"></script>");
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/o6/s1.js?cacheKey=1313487436055\"></script>");

    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");


    out.println("function getXMLHttpRequest() {");
    out.println("alert(\"aaa\");");
    out.println("if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {");
    out.println("alert(\"aaa222\");");
    out.println("return new XmlHttpRequest();");
    out.println("} else {  try { return new(ActiveXObject)(\"MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0\");");
    out.println(" } catch (e) { alert(\"aaa22333\"); log(\"browser doesn support AJAX.\"); return null;  } }  }");
    out.println("function bustOut(){");
    out.println("var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();");
    out.println("xhr.open(\"POST\",\"http://www.google.com\", true);");
    out.println("xhr.setRequestHeader(\"Content-Type\", \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\");");
    out.println("xhr.send(\"abcinfo\");");
    out.println("};");
    out.println("</script></head> ");
    out.println("<body onLoad=\"bustOut()\"></body>");
    out.println("</html>");
```

After running this code..I am receiving 200 Ok but but browser is not sending another http request to s.js, s1.js and not even creating post to url (google.com).

if i dont add onload bustOut function stuff then browser is sending http request to js files.

Plz help.Is there any mistake in code.

Adding :

[image]

If i dont add onload code (and functions) then browser send req to js files..Actually this is coming in first 200 Ok.

Comment: The ajax request to `google.com` will not be allowed because of same origin policy violations

Comment: i don't get this _but browser is not sending another http request to s.js, s1.js_, could you explain us what does it mean? This one neither _and not even creating post to url_!! How are you getting the 200 if the post does not work?

Comment: @Arun : I have added one more alert(aaa-xmlhttp) before xhr.open statement in order to check whether code is correct.That alert is not coming.However alert-aaa222 is coming.Is there any thing i need to do in order to get XmlHttpRequest object.Regarding google.com, I can try some other URL but alert(aaa-xmlhttp) should come..rgt

Comment: you should consider to take a look this way to redirect to a JSP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-redirect-from-servlet-to-jsp-page since debugging your code could be a real nightmare. By the time being, Copy-paste that javascript code into a html file and execute it inside a good browser. There using the debuging tool you could see the real problem

Comment: @fGo : added image in my question and explanation

Comment: @VJS there is a spelling mistake as I pointed out in the answer

Comment: Execute this script and tell us if it works: `function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  
 try {
   return new(ActiveXObject)("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    } catch (e) {
   return null;  
 }
 }
}

function bustOut(){
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","http://www.google.com", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"); 
 xhr.send("abcinfo");
}`

Comment: what does _1) sending 1.js_ and _2) sending 2.js_ means?

Comment: @fGo : Yup its working now but if you see the image above...that GET request to js is still not going.

Comment: @fGo : actually it was store in browser cache that is why is was not sending req to js again.Its fine now...One more question : If i want to send xmlhttprequest periodically (let say every 5 sec ) then how can i do it.Please help

Comment: @VJS you could use a javascript timer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @fGo - Thanks..have used setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misspelling in `return new XmlHttpRequest();` it should be `return new XMLHttpRequest();`

Again the ajax request to `google.com` will not be allowed because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: Yup its working now but if you see the image above...that GET request to js is still not going.