# Pages resources such as css or javascript are not retrieved when Servlet uses sub path

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, servlets

Here is my Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "UserAreaServlet",
            urlPatterns = {"/user/",
                           "/user/info",
                           "/user/update",
                           "/user/updated",
                           "/user/remove",
                           "/user/removed"})
public class UserAreaServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @EJB
    private UtilBeanInterface utilBean;
    @EJB
    private UserManagerBeanInterface userManagerBean;

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String userPath = request.getServletPath();

        if(userPath.equals("/user/"))
        {
                      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/userarea/userarea.jsp").forward(request, response); 

        }

        if(userPath.equals("/user/info"))
        {

        }

        if(userPath.equals("/user/update"))
        {


        }

        if(userPath.equals("/user/remove"))
        {
        }

        if(userPath.equals("/user/removed"))
        {

        }
    }
```

I have a problem. When I go to the /user/info or /user/update i got the page but not the resources linked to it such as css or javascript. Why? I'm using java ee 7

Comment: Please provide more details about your actual problem.  How are your resources packaged? How do you access your resources and what exactly is happening?

Comment: What I would like to know if it is really possibile to do that I mean to do.Calling the various page in that way is right?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking about. Is it [how to redirect from servlet to jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-redirect-from-servlet-to-jsp-page)?

Answer (score 0):

File references must be defined referring to the servlet context, that is, in your html code just refer to css and js files not considering the html file context but the servlet one.

For example, suppose to have the following situation:

- "**html**" folder containing ***myHtml.html*** file
- "**css**" folder containing ***myCss.css*** file
- "**template**" folder containing both "**html**" and "**css**" folders
- "**servlet**" folder containing the servlet related to ***myHtml.html***

In order to include "***myCss.css***" in "***myHtml.html***", you will have to write :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/myCss.css">
```

instead of :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/myCss.css">
```