# After ajax call redirect the response to another jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have an ajax call from a jsp page where it sends request to the ModelandView class in the controller.

**Ajax call in test.jsp**

```
function currentposition(l1, l2) {
    var url="home/test";
    var data= 'lat1=' + l1 + '&lat2=' + l2;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:data,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(responseJSON){
            alert(responseJSON);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ModelandView gettest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelandView responseView = new ModelandView(new JsonView());
    //some code here
    if (somecondition) {
        response.addObject("JSONdata", vehicleID);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not present");
    }
    return responseView;
}
```

I am getting response from the controller to test.jsp and I am getting the desired results. But I want to redirect the results to another.jsp where the result should appear in the drop down list as follows.

**another.jsp**

```
<select class="test" id="vehicle-id">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why use AJAX when you need to re-direct with some data?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja Sir I need to send data to controller and get back response so I used ajax

Comment: Duplicate of 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-redirect-from-servlet-to-jsp-page][1]

Answer (score 1):

Try these adding in success response of your AJAX call:

```
var surl = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/registration';
                window.location.replace(surl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try through form submit like:

```
...
success:function(responseJSON){
   var form = $('<form></form>').attr('action','another.jsp');
   $(form).attr('method','POST');
   var ele = $('<input type="text">').attr('name','txtjson');  
   $(ele).val(responseJSON); 
   $(ele).appendTo($(form));
   $(form).appendTo('body');
   $(form).submit();

}
...
```

Then in your another.jsp file just receive the POST variable `txtjson`.

Comment: That is a very creative solution, but then you might as well put the form directly in the HTML source already with a hidden input which you can update and submit upon success :)

Comment: @Think Different : Sir thanks for the solution. I received the txtjson as request.getparameter("txtjson"); still not getting the output.

Comment: @Vidya make sure you have this line `$(ele).val(responseJSON);` as in the above answer.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent : sir yes i added that still not getting the required result. Is it fine if i just add request .getParameter("txtjson"); as a scriplet in my jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Write another controller which returns `another.jsp`

From your `test.jsp`, give `window.location = /home/test?lat1=' + l1 + '&lat2=' + l2;`

once the json data is processed, redirect to the another controller.