# JSP File Output If/Else Problems

Tags: java, html, database, jsp

So I have a simple login form in JSP that connects to a database and checks if the user is in the table

When it checks it either prints on the webpage

Welcome + User

else it prints Invalid password try again

The problem is that it never prints Invalid password try again it just gos to a blank page

It will print Welcome + User if they are in the table I cant seem to figure out why it only those half the statement

Its problay something simple but I cant figure it out

```
<body>
        <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %><%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %><%String user = request.getParameter("userid");
            session.putValue("userid", user);
            String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/socusers", "root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where user_id='" + user + "'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString(2).equals(pwd)) {
                    out.println("welcome " + user);
                } else {
                    out.println("Invalid password try again");
                }
            }


        %>
    </body>
```

Comment: I think you should learn about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Also, [disable browser caching](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm).

Comment: And, you probably shouldn't have `session.putValue("userid", user);` before validating the `user`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because your query is not returning anything, therefore you will never enter on that else because you didn't enter on the first if `if (rs.next()) {` Try adding an else to this if **or** with a user that do exist but with just the wrong password! You will see it prints your error.

Something like:

```
String message = "";
if (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString(2).equals(pwd)) {
         message =  "welcome " + user;
    } else {
         message = "Invalid password try again";
    }
}else{
    message = "Invalid user try again";
}
out.println(message);
```

Also, consider in using the tables columns on your select instead of the asterisk. If someone changes that table (column orders for instance) your system will break.

Comment: Worked like a dream thank you, just one other thing is there any way to change how the messages are /output, cause right now they are a tiny string on the side of the window, I would like to output them as say a <h2> tag ?

Comment: @ClarkPamler93 Yes of course. Remember that everything that you output is in fact HTML so, you just need to use html on your output string, something like `message = "<h1>Invalid user try again</h1>";` and the browser will do the job for you!

Comment: sry and again one other thing is there a way say to add in a function say one that will hide whatever is on the page if the user enters the wrong name or password to the if/else string ? thanks again

Comment: Well you can redirect to a specific page if there is an error. It is easy then hiding everything on your current page. In the other page you can add a go back button.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622320/460557

Comment: Hi again judt one more thing how do I alter the "Welcome " + user function with html I tryed using the <h1> tags and put it around Welcome but it didnt affect the user part

Comment: It would be `message =  "<h1>Welcome " + user + "</h1>";` Just concatenate as String