# J2EE redirect to an external URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am developing a web application in which the servlet takes informaiton from index.jsp and does some data processing. After that, I want my application to redirect the user to an external url.

How can I do that? Should I redirect in the servlet or make the servlet call a jsp page which calls the url? and how to do that explicitly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below URL should help you:

[how to redirect from servlet to jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-redirect-from-servlet-to-jsp-page)

If the redirect should happen based on some condition use the following in an if condition based on request data you get from index.jsp.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: thnks! exaclty what I needed

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for creating a seperate jsp for url redirection. After performing the required operations in the servlet, simply call sendredirect method of the response object.
'reponse.sendRedirect(url)' will do.

Answer (score -1):

make the servlet call a jsp page which calls the url.