# How to redirect to jsp from post request

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets

Is there a way to redirect to another jsp from a `post` request?
There are question like [how-to-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-redirect-from-servlet-to-jsp-page), but all the answers works only in `get` requests.
My code:

```
String pathTOjSP = "/JSP/Choose.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(pathTOjSP);
```

I have 2 problems:

1.In the response at the client side I get the `jsp` as text - `<html><head>...` and no redirect occurs.

2.In the jsp, the java attributes - `request.setAttribute("name", "test");` are `null`.

Thanks for any help.