# i want to know after data save same page is open using javascript functon?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I want know how to reload the same page after data has been entered.
I have two pages: one jsp and one servlet.
In my program, after I click the submit button, I want to open the same data entry page, but I cannot do it using javascript.
I want to reopen the same data entry page after clicking the sumbit button.

Here is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name = Login method="post" action="ValueAdd.java"> 
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="last_name">
<br>
City name:<br>
<input type="text" name="city_name">
<br>
Email Id:<br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
</body>
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
package com.rmspl.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ValueAdd
 */

public class ValueAdd extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("here in servlet...");

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

    String n = request.getParameter("first_name");
    String p = request.getParameter("last_name");
    String e = request.getParameter("city_name");
    String c = request.getParameter("email");


    try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_data","root","root");
    PreparedStatement ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("insert into users(first_name,last_name,city_name,email) values (?,?,?,?)");


    ps.setString(1,n);
    ps.setString(2,p);
    ps.setString(3, e);
    ps.setString(4,c);
    ps.execute();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Data Inserted Sucessfully");


    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
    System.out.println(e1);

    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Use `RequestDispatcher` to dispatch your request to another page.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621998/how-to-send-redirect-to-jsp-page-in-servlet) .

Comment: Can anybody give me a example? because i am new in javascript. please give me an example above my code.